# Reassociating QuickLook file associations

Tags: finder, macos, quicklook

Today I noticed the QuickLook feature stopped displaying .jpg, .png, and .pdf file previews.  Desktop icons for *these* types don't show thumbnails.  Pressing SPACE with the file selected in Finder just shows the iconic type of file it is.

And I've tried the [CNET recommended fixes](http://www.cnet.com/news/fixing-quick-look-issues-in-os-x/):

- `qlmanage -r`
- `qlmanage -r cache`
- checking in `/Macintosh HD/System/Library/QuickLook/`, `/Macintosh HD/Library/QuickLook/`, and `~/Library/QuickLook/`
- removing the files called `com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper.plist`, `com.apple.quicklookconfig.plist`, and `com.apple.QuickLookDaemon.plist`

Other QuickLook file types work well.

At first, it looked like the control was taken over by Lytro:

```
2016-02-29 17:53:52.461 qlmanage[2351:64583] [qlinfinite] Instantiated plugin in host with identifier (null)
2016-02-29 17:53:52.461 qlmanage[2351:64583] [qlinfinite] Found 61 system generators
2016-02-29 17:53:52.462 qlmanage[2351:64583] [qlinfinite] Registered generator CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7f96e9818e00 </Applications/Lytro.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/LytroLFR.qlgenerator> (bundle, loaded) for type public.jpeg
```

Reinstalling the new Lytro desktop, things changed.

More disturbing was this... Dropbox seems to be taking control:

```
$ qlmanage -m plugins | grep -i public.image
  public.image -> /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DropboxQL.qlgenerator (2)
```

Creating a new account on my Mac shows things working fine. So it has to be something about my configuration ...except that I have no `~/Library/QuickLook` directory, and I also do not have any `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.[Qq]uicklook*` entries either.

At this point, multiple reboots, even with Safe Mode do not resolve the issue.

Is there a way to reset the QuickLook associations back to default?

Also, could someone post their `qlmanage -m plugins` output from a working system?

---

More weird, previewing *via the command line* using `qlmanage -p anyimagefile.jpg` from the Terminal works just fine!

That said, it does emit this cryptic error:

```
2016-02-29 19:10:41.835 qlmanage[3873:130464] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x8f03, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2016-02-29 19:10:42.028 qlmanage[3873:130464] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xbb37, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2016-02-29 19:10:42.029 qlmanage[3873:130464] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xbc1b, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2016-02-29 19:10:42.029 qlmanage[3873:130464] void __CFPasteboardSetup() : Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions
```

---

I found a similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127651/quicklook-stopped-working-with-xcodes-m-and-h-file-suddenly) that had a number of debugging techniques in it.

Performing my same command line preview with a high debug setting `qlmanage -d 4 -p anyimagefile.jpg | grep public.image` resulted in seeing extensions registered.

```
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Image.qlgenerator> for public.image
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DropboxQL.qlgenerator> for public.image
```

So, I blatantly renamed the `DropboxQL.qlgenerator`, which curiously had a *very recent* modification time on it, and suddenly the preview-using-space problem went away.

Finder still does not display icon previews for these types.

(reboot.)

Now it does.

Comment: I'm really hesitant to point the finger at a Dropbox update; those folks really have their act together.  But it's really odd that taking their QuickLook extension out of the equation solved the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Fingers should definitely be pointed to Dropbox.  Have you already complained to them?

Comment: @user1155120 The DMG only has an installer that will download the actual Dropbox app (that in turn contains the QuickLook generator).

Comment: I made a forum post: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204921503-Dropbox-3-15-51-broke-hijacked-QuickLook-on-OS-X-

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?build=3.14.7&plat=mac&type=full

Comment: The DropboxQL.qlgenerator file shows up in the full installer for beta version 3.15.51  in the app Dropbox.App/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DropboxQL.qlgenerator.  You might install the stable version (3.14.7).

Comment: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205867666-Beta-Build-3-15-51

Comment: You can turn off the re-upgrade to the beta version by unchecking the box in your profile on dropbox.com that says "Include me on early releases". Someone put that item back in user profiles to allow going back to 3.14.7.

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is a Dropbox issue.  While I had raised a question on Twitter, thanks to @szabolcs for creating a [forum post](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204921503-Dropbox-3-15-51-broke-hijacked-QuickLook-on-OS-X-), where others have chimed into.

Remove the `/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/DropboxQL.qlgenerator` file.

@user1155120 was spot on; the beta version should be unchecked on the dropbox.com site, to prevent getting unstable updates. Download a new copy (v3.14.7 as of the time of this writing in 2016-03-02) and reinstall.

Comment: I can't believe it's been two years and Dropbox haven't fixed this.  I'm on High Sierra and quicklook doesn't work as long as dropboxQL.qlgenerator file is installed.